# NSURLProtocol canInitWithRequest calling 5 times

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, protocols, nsurlprotocol

I'm working on a `hybrid application framework`. I needed to catch all `request` from somewhere and i fond some blog it says i can do that with using custom `NSURLProtocol`. I did everything it says but i have some problems.

When i load `http://www.google.com` to my webview, it calls `canInitWithRequest` for 5 times in `mycustomprotocol.m`. but i dont want to call 5 times.

> 1. 2014-03-13 15:51:50.675 Hybrid[9334:60b] `http://www.google.com/`
> 2. 2014-03-13 15:51:50.677 Hybrid[9334:60b] `http://www.google.com/`
> 3. 2014-03-13 15:51:50.683 Hybrid[9334:60b] `http://www.google.com/`
> 4. 2014-03-13 15:51:50.685 Hybrid[9334:60b] `http://www.google.com/`
> 5. 2014-03-13 15:51:50.686 Hybrid[9334:60b] `http://www.google.com/`
> 6. 2014-03-13 15:51:54.474 Hybrid[9334:3807] `http://www.google.com/`
> 7. 2014-03-13 15:51:54.508 Hybrid[9334:3807] `http://www.google.com/images/logo_ret_2.png`
> 8. 2014-03-13 15:51:54.509 Hybrid[9334:3807] `http://www.google.com/images/logo_ret_2.png`
> 9. 2014-03-13 15:51:54.510 Hybrid[9334:3807] `http://www.google.com/images/logo_ret_2.png`

I only loaded `google` for once. Why is `canInitWithRequest` calling five times before `startLoading`?

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

Same question is answered here >

[NSURLProtocol canInitWithRequest: called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238106/nsurlprotocol-caninitwithrequest-called-multiple-times)

Its said to be normal behaviour